# app.EnterText() doesn`t enter text to entry in Android 7 and higher in XamarinUiTest

Tags: android, xamarin.android, uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

I successfully ran my test on:

- physical Android 5.1;
- Android 6.0.1 emulator;
- testCloud devices 5.1, 5.1.1, 6.0.1

But when I try to run my UITest on Android emulator 7.0 and in testCloud on android devices 7 and higher, it ignores `app.EnterText() method`
It taps into Username entry then it must enter text into it but it doesn`t do it and taps into Password entry without any text entering. How can I solve this issue with Android 7?

```
[Test]
public void Android_7()
{
    app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("UsernameId"));
    app.Tap(c => c.Marked("UsernameId"));
    app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("UsernameId"), "www");
    app.Tap(c => c.Marked("PasswordId"));
    app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("PasswordId"), "testpsswd");
    app.Screenshot("Logining");
    app.Tap(c => c.Marked("SIGN IN"));
    app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Exigo"));
    app.Screenshot("Dashboard");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
app.Tap (c => c.Marked ("UsernameId"));
app.EnterText ("www");

It is better not to specify for EnterText field in which you enter text, sometimes it is buggy and not called

Comment: I tried this way but it didn`t help me to figure it out